# C# - Generic Action?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, action

I'm using .NET Framework 4.0. Looking the documentation for Action (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.100).aspx), they give this example comparing delegate to Action:

```
delegate void DisplayMessage(string message);

public class TestCustomDelegate
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DisplayMessage messageTarget;
        ...
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class TestAction1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Action<string> messageTarget;
        ...
    }
}
```

But, how do I create this using an Action instead of a delegate?

```
delegate void DisplayMessage<T>(T message);

public class TestCustomDelegate
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DisplayMessage<string> messageTarget;
        ...
    }
}
```

Edit: I forgot the type definition in my messageTarget declaration. Added it now.

Comment: I too have the need for a caller of a method to provide a generic action, so I feel your pain :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your delegate is exactly the same as `Action<T>`, but with a different name.

You can use it the same way.

Comment: @MikePrecup: I'm not sure what you're talking about; there is no function in any of his examples.  And, it is unfortunately impossible to bind a delegate to an open generic method.

Comment: Ah. I understand. You can't use Action to define new generic delegates because Action is a generic delegate. Thanks. Marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

For an existing method (like DisplayMessage)

```
public void DisplayMessage<T>(T message)
{
    //do stuff with s
    if (message is string)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

Action<string> messageTarget = new Action<string>(DisplayMessage);
messageTarget.Invoke("Testing");  //or use beginInvoke/endInvoke
```

Can use lambda's too:

```
Action<string> messageTarget = new Action<string>(s =>
                {
                    //do stuff with s                    
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                });
messageTarget.Invoke("Testing");  //or use beginInvoke/endInvoke
```